# How to implement image region click listener for multiple screen size in android?

Tags: java, android, image, layout

I want to create fullscreen activity that load image ad in fullscreen. The example image is like this:

[image]

Note that, the button is also part of image. Here is the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ad_image">

</LinearLayout>
```

You can see the image is loaded with `android:background`.

What I want to achieve is: when the "Button" image portion is clicked, it will do something (like launching another activity), as well as the "Close [X]" rectangle at top-right corner, when clicked, it will close the activity.

It seems it's easy to implement click logic on the region part of "Button" drawing. So far I found two ways:

1. Set ontouch listener on LinearLayout and check it's X and Y coordinate for the Button drawing region
2. Put invisible `ImageView` on top of "Button" image in layout, and set onclick listener.

But the problem is: there are multiple screen sizes and resolutions across many android devices. So I wonder if those two solusions can be used in portable way across different screen size?

Since the image might be stretched when loaded in different screen resolution, and that means for solution #1: I have to adjust X & Y number. And for solution #2: the invisible ImageView's position might get synched-off from the Button drawing.

So anyone know better solution for this?

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to use invisible click placeholder solution. Here is the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ad_image"
    android:id="@+id/adLayout"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:id="@+id/adImageLayout"
        android:onClick="adImageClicked">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`adImageLayout` is the click placeholder for the button drawing.

Comment: I'd use a RelativeLayout with an azure background, then add a TextView and a Button (Close X and Button). The first one would have a 9 patch as a background, the latter a rounded corners drawable. Very easy and not as memory consuming as a full-screen picture.

Comment: @DerGolem: the image shown above is just a an example, the real image that I will use is not a solid color background image like that.

Comment: Oh, I see. Anyway, the TextView + Button overlayed on the parent's background technique seems to me more convenient over implementing some unnecessary custom logic.

Comment: @DerGolem: It's not that simple unfortunately. The ad image could be like [this](http://www.adbuddiz.com/images/web/android.png). And I'm not an artist, so the image will be provided by someone else. I'm just doing the code logic.

Comment: Well, the buttons are simply **transparent** TextViews or ImageViews (which are **clickable**) holding a graphic - you wouldn't tell that they are "squared". So, again, there's no need for a custom logic.

Comment: @DerGolem: could you show me the example of layout from your solution.

Comment: Yes, give me a while. It's all about design, rather than code (I'll make a shared onClick Listener referenced in the layout and distinguish which is the caller in code). Let me prepare the example images first, derived from your example (thi will require some time, the rest is very easy).

Answer (score 1):

Or supply an `image` for each of the densities that android supports, and add `layout` that position the button accordingly for each Image Or much better yet just make the lower region of the image clickable. 
The `button` itself  is big and almost cover the entire region of the lower screen. users will not try to click there if they don't want to click the button. I can tell you from first hand that this is what Ad companies doing in situations like that.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="your_background">

   <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="120dp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:background="#000"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---- UPDATE ----

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:text="My Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="24dp"
    />

</FrameLayout>

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);

        final int heightPixels = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        button.setTranslationY(- heightPixels / 3 / 2);
    }



}
```

Comment: How about if the button drawing is in the middle?

Comment: so make your invisible button `width` to `match_parent` and align the button center in the parent.

Comment: I've just tried, it seems invisible button can't be clicked.

Comment: It's simply by adding `android:onClick="buttonClicked"` in `<Button>` which also has `android:visibility="invisible"`, then I put a showing Toast code in the `buttonClicked` method, but the onClick method doesn't get called. Even setting onTouchListener on the invisible button doesn't help too. Finally, I solved it by using a `LinearLayout` as the invisible click placeholder to the button drawing (see the edited question). What do you think? Is it good enough or do you have better suggestion?

Comment: Hi, I have tried your layout, but it doesn't work. Please see this [screenshot](http://i57.tinypic.com/nxovmd.jpg). The button is showing as blue dot at top-left corner.

Comment: Have no idea why it didn't work, i tried it and of course it worked...change to Relative layout which gives you easier position.

Comment: Maybe you added the button to one of the inner layouts?

Comment: I just tried your new solution, it's much better now but still can't get clicked. The problem is the `android:visibility`, if it's set to `invisible` or `gone`, the view object can't respond to click or touch.

Comment: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`. add this to the button instead of setting visibilty

Comment: Is your solution works for any screen size? If not, what variable that I must change? Is it the layout_height?

Comment: well yeah, you need to know the screen height in order to be sure. you can get the screen height by `activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels` and the set the `ImageButton` height accordingly. but a `120dp` is a good start

Comment: This is not what I want. You don't even use my sample image. Look at my answer, could you do same as my answer but using your own solution? Note that, my solution has the only button area clickable, it's not acceptable for user to be able to click left/right blank area of the button.

Comment: suud, good luck, i've tried to help you without success, go on and implement it the way you see fit

Answer (score 1):

I decided to answer my question. I improved my original solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ad_image"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/xbutton"
            android:onClick="xButtonClicked"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the schema of the Layout:

[image]

The close button is loaded with ImageView.

So basically I'm just using `layout_weight` trick here. I avoided hardcoded dpi, as it will cause different LinearLayout's width/height result in different screen size.

I have tested with several screen resolutions (except tablet size), it works fine. I don't need to supply different image and layout files for multiple densities. And the required code in the Activity class is very minimal, there are only code to set fullscreen:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and the `onClick` event methods.

Of course, if you can found better solution, let me know.

Comment: well sorry for what i'm about to say but your solution is plain horrible. you are 7! `ViewGroups` in order to position 2! `Views`. You should definitely reconsider

Comment: If using your solution, the region outside the button drawing is still clickable. At least my solution can still gain accuracy of the click region on top of the each buttons. Don't worry, I won't accept my own answer for sure.

Comment: But you just did it wrong. your `weight` is just saying: `70%` percent of the screen is not `clickable` and out of the `30%` left make x% clickable. You could easily do it with the Solution i gave you but with only 1 `ViewGroup` and 1-2 view (for each button) instead of your 9.

Comment: But your solution use hardcoded dp, that means I have to supply each layout for different densities.

Comment: As i mentioned in my comments your `SHOULD NOT` use hard coded dp but calculate the height of your layout grammatically and then assign the desired height to your button. i even showed u how to get the screen dimensions

Comment: Can you give a complete code of your solution including the layout xml using example image above? Here is the 320x480 size of the example image above: http://i59.tinypic.com/2j3pukl.jpg, or you can also use your own image, but please upload the image here if you do, so I can try it.

Comment: added code. button is approximately at the bottom third half of the screen

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to work with buttons and views, you could just think at X and Y in form of fractions of the whole screen width and height.

Let's say the clickable area goes from 1/3 to 2/3 of the screen width. Then you can just recall the actual ScreenWidth (in dp, pixels, or whatever) and say at runtime that the clickable area goes from (1/3)*ScreenWidth to (2/3)*ScreenWidth.

Same for Ys, or for the close button. Designer will then make the background according to these ratios.